# How to use custom field in Shopware 5 item url?

Tags: php, symfony, url-routing, shopware

I am trying to use a custom field's value in seo url template in shopware but it does not seem to work.

The guide here does the exact same thing what I do:

https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-5-en/settings/seo

SEO URLs item template:

```
deal/{if $sArticle.custom_url}{$sArticle.custom_url}{else}{$sArticle.supplier|replace:'.':'' }-{$sArticle.name|replace:'.':'' }{/if}
```

Is there something wrong with this part?

```
{if $sArticle.custom_url}{$sArticle.custom_url}{/if}
```

Comment: Can you describe more detailed? Have you set up it there: https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-5-en/settings/seo#seo-router-settings ? Have you cleaned cache after that?

Comment: I already found the cause, I will not post the answer with details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happened:
I created a new custom field,
added it as a variable in seo router settings,
put a value in item's overview,
then cleaned all the caches, but it was not going there.

As I understood the reason is that only attr1-attr19 are available to the router. When I tried with the attr1 it worked.